# AngularJS routeProvider generate routes from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to get route parsing for `$routeProvider` to generate .when()'s from array. Here is the code in app.js that I've tried. This generates correct routes, but causes infinite loops of "Tried to load AngularJS more than once". I only load angularjs in the index. html file, into which the view is rendered. How can I get routes from array to work? Array structure is `"route":"fileName.html"`.

```
var dynape = angular.module("dynape",['ngRoute','dynape.controllers','dynape.services','ngCookies']);

dynape.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/siteconf', {skipSetup: true});

    db.get("pages").then(function(doc) {
        var tmp = doc;
        delete tmp["_id"];
        delete tmp["_rev"];
        delete tmp["/"];
        for(p in tmp) {
            console.log(p.toString());
            $routeProvider.when(p.toString(), {
                controller: "SiteController",
                templateUrl: "views/pages/"+tmp[p]
            });
        }
    });
    // Follwing routes never change
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        controller: 'SiteController',
        templateUrl: "views/frontPage.html"
    }).when("/admin",{
        controller: 'AdminLoginController',
        templateUrl: "views/admin/login.html"
    }).when("/admin/setup", {
        controller: 'SetupController',
        templateUrl: "views/admin/setup.html"
    }).when("/admin/dashboard", {
        controller: 'AdminActionController',
        templateUrl: "views/admin/dashboard.html"
    }).when("/admin/pages", {
        controller: 'AdminActionController',
        templateUrl: "views/admin/pages.html"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });




    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
]);

angular.module("dynape.controllers",[]);
angular.module("dynape.services",[]);
```

The index.html into which I render the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="dynape">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A Dynape Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/components-base.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/gridsys.css" media="screen">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap" ng-view>
    </div>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/pouchdb.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/image-picker.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/angular.route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/services/AuthenticationService.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/controllers/AdminLoginController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/controllers/AdminActionController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/controllers/SetupController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/controllers/SiteController.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are there in app.js

Comment: @Namal the first code block is app.js

Comment: Did u check view source to check whether is there duplicate angularjs libraries?

Comment: @Namal did you or did you not read my question's description? I specifically stated, that angularjs and all libs are loaded ONLY in index,html.

Comment: I did. This error occurs accidentally included the library more than once in any form. May be have bootstraped manually.

Comment: @Namal K, since I don't have double includes, that seems to not be the problem... onwards to wait for an answer on the array-parsing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can't access $routeProvider outside of .config

My guess would be that db.get is a call to your server which runs async.  Then, by the time that call comes back, the routeProvider is already registered.

In other words, your code is being executed in the following order:

1. Create app (groovy)
2. Call CONFIG with $routeProvider (swell)
3. Call db.get(<callback>) (fine)
4. Manually setup $routeProvider.when with 6 specific routes (awesome)

.... Now, angularJs has been bootstrapped ...

5. db.get returns from the server and calls <callback> (uh-oh)
6. Attempting to access/change $routeProvider with new 'dynamic' routes (oops)

**2 Potential Solutions:**

A.  bootstrap/config angularJs AFTER the db.get() returns.  Never tried this ... I guess it could work, but seems risky.

B.  DEFER route configuration using a decorator.  [there is an excellent blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2783-deferring-route-configuration-using-decorators-and-route-resolution-in-angularjs.htm) on this topic which seems to do what you want to do.

It would mean that all your dynamic routes would need the same "root" (eg - they all follow the format "/other/:route*"), but that's the only restriction.

I'd go with option B.  Seems like a good plan!

Comment: Cool!  I like that option.  I was afraid that you would run into problems if you bootstrapped after the dom was settled and your other js code was loaded.  So are you accepting this answer, then?

Comment: Somehow  my code started working.... I'll rewrite this with angularpouchdb anyways, that should remove some of the timing issues.